# Google calendar freezing up on my iMac

Tags: google-calendar

My Google calendar freezes up on my iMac [at home, where I use Safari] but I never have this problem on my PC [at work, where I use Mozilla]. I can't make appts or see details of existing appts. I understood that Safari works best on iMacs, but this is rather maddening. Will Google Calendar work better with another browser on an iMac?

Comment: Have you tried any other browsers on your mac?

Comment: Just use Chrome instead of Safari.